# \newglossarystyle grouping entries in glossary list incorrectly

Tags: glossaries, glossary

I'm trying to lay out the glossary using the `glossaries` package. I'm using the `index` style and I'm trying to add a colon after the acronym.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronyms,nomain]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{Alpha Bravo Charlie}
\newacronym{NASA}{NASA}{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}
\newacronym{NSA}{NSA}{National Security Agency}
\newacronym{NATO}{NATO}{North Atlantic Treaty Organization}
\newacronym{EU}{EU}{European Union}
\newacronym{ECDC}{ECDC}{European Centre for Disease Prevention and Control}
\newacronym{EWRS}{EWRS}{Early Warning and Response System}
\newacronym{USA}{USA}{United States of America}

\begin{document}

\gls{ABC}
\gls{NASA}
\gls{NSA}
\gls{NATO}
\gls{EU}
\gls{ECDC}
\gls{EWRS}
\gls{USA}

\setglossarystyle{index}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace{8pt}}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Glossary]

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
    \setglossarystyle{index}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace{8pt}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \textbf{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}:}}
        \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\\
    }%
}
\setglossarystyle{mystyle}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the first glossary, which uses the `index` style alone, properly groups items alphabetically. However, when I use my own style, which appends a colon to the entry name, suddenly the grouping becomes incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\par` rather than `\\` seems to give the desired result, but the real problem appears to be that your `\glossentry` deviates too far from the `\glossentry` defined in the `index` style, which uses a list and expects `\item`.

Instead modifying the `\glossentry` defined in the `index` style to insert a colon

```
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item\glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
    \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
    \glstreenamefmt{:}%  <== This line added
    \glstreepredesc \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2%
}%
```

seems more like what you would want.

[image: Compiled code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronyms,nomain]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{Alpha Bravo Charlie}
\newacronym{NASA}{NASA}{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}
\newacronym{NSA}{NSA}{National Security Agency}
\newacronym{NATO}{NATO}{North Atlantic Treaty Organization}
\newacronym{EU}{EU}{European Union}
\newacronym{ECDC}{ECDC}{European Centre for Disease Prevention and Control}
\newacronym{EWRS}{EWRS}{Early Warning and Response System}
\newacronym{USA}{USA}{United States of America}

\begin{document}

\gls{ABC}
\gls{NASA}
\gls{NSA}
\gls{NATO}
\gls{EU}
\gls{ECDC}
\gls{EWRS}
\gls{USA}

\setglossarystyle{index}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace{8pt}}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Glossary]

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
    \setglossarystyle{index}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace{8pt}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item\glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
        \glstreenamefmt{:}%
        \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
        \glstreepredesc \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2%
    }%
}
\setglossarystyle{mystyle}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, I assumed `index` specifically didn't use a list, since it's not listed in 13.1.1 List Styles in the documentation. Thank you.

Comment: If you dig into the [documented code](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-code.pdf) you can find the exact definitions used by searching for `\newglossarystyle{index}`.